# Joining two arrays and echoing the results

Tags: php, arrays, join

I have 3 arrays $personal1 , $personal2 and $business , each one holds 1 field from each query,
so for example 'Mr' 'John Smith' 'Johnscorp Ltd'.

I am trying to construct the following if query >>

```
$personal2 = $userinfo->leadname;
$personal1 = $userinfo->salutation;
$business = $userinfo->businessname;


if ($personal1=="")
$name = $business;
else
$name = $personal1;
echo '<h1>NAME:';
echo $name;
echo '</h1>';
```

What it does is check to see if the salutation is blank or not, if the field is blank the business name is echo'd instead.

The problem I have is how do I merge the personal and personal2 into one array ?.

I am not sure if I can do this :

```
$personal2 = $userinfo->leadname;
$personal1 = $userinfo->salutation;
$business = $userinfo->businessname;


if ($personal1=="")
$name = $business;
else
$name = $personal1 & $personal2;
echo '<h1>NAME:';
echo $name;
echo '</h1>';
```

or if I can do this ?

```
$personal = $userinfo->salutation,$userinfo->leadname;
$business = $userinfo->businessname;


if ($personal1=="")
$name = $business;
else
$name = $personal;
echo '<h1>NAME:';
echo $name;
echo '</h1>';
```

or if both are incorrect as I dont seem to be getting any results :-S .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the first example you have should be working, just replace

`$name = $personal1 & $personal2;`

with

`$name = $personal1 . ' ' . $personal2;`

this will join these string with a space between them

PS: Didn't you think strings instead of arrays ?

Comment: thanks for that, yes I meant strings I think, im not too hot with my terminology :-S.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit puzzled because you've stated multiple times that you're using arrays, however in your example, it appears that you're using objects.

Anyways, if all you need is to merge $personal1 and $personal2, 
instead of using:

```
$name = $personal1 & $personal2;
```

you can just use:

```
$name = $personal1 + $personal2;
```

If it's a string you need:

```
$name = $personal1 . ' ' . $personal2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array_merge()
```

or just the `+` operator